# How to Process Form Request

Tags: forms

So... I have a form build into a WordPress page like this:

```
<form action="/help" method="GET">
                        <h2 class="heading post-title">Contact Us</h2>
                        <label>Name:</label><br>
                        <input type="text" name="name" /><br>
                        <label>Email:</label><br>
                        <input type="text" name="email" /><br>
                        <label>Subject:</label><br>
                        <input type="text" name="subject" /><br>
                        <label>Message:</label><br>
                        <textarea name="msg" style="width:200px;height:380px"></textarea><br><br>
                        <input type="submit" style="width:206px;margin:0 auto;border:1px solid gray;border-radius:3px;background-color:orange;color:white" />
                        <br>
                        <label style="color:red"><?php if(isset($_GET['success'])) echo "Your message has successfully been sent!"; else echo "<br>"; ?></label>
                      </form>
```

And /help redirects to the same page which contains this code, so I'm trying to redirect the page to itself.
Same page which contains the form above (page-help.php), also contains some php in the beginning for processing the data, like this:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['message']))
{
 // require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

  $mail = new PHPMailer;

  $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
  $mail->Host = 'mail.arkzel.com';  // Specify main and backup server
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
  $mail->Username = 'arsham@arkzel.com';                            // SMTP username
  $mail->Password = 'Xwbs*YR!';                           // SMTP password
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

  $mail->From = $_POST['email'];;
  $mail->FromName = $_POST['name'];;
  $mail->addAddress('arsham@arkzel.com');               // Name is optional

  $mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
  $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

  $mail->Subject = $_POST['subject'];;
  $mail->Body    = $_POST['message'];
  $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

  if(!$mail->send()) {
     echo 'Message could not be sent.';
     echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
     exit;
  }
  header("location: help?success=1");
}
?>
```

But instead, what I get is a 404: Not Found message.
Much confused.

Comment: You just need to change form method from GET to POST. `<form action="/help" method="POST">`

Comment: @Shazzad - have you actually tried this? same issue - you can't send GET *or* POST vars that clash with WP query vars.

Comment: WP doesn't parse query variable using GET ot POST method, rather they do it using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. Moreover, even if wp parse query variable using GET or POST, they do not override these GLOBALS. And @V0R73X is getting value using $_POST, and doing redirection therefore. So there shouldn't be any conflict. I haven't tested this code, but i think it should be working. He is getting error, because he has miss-matched the FORM method in comparison and submission.

Comment: @Shazzad again, I invite you to try it out and see for yourself. changing GET to POST exhibits the same problem. output the query vars on the `parse_request` action and you will see in both GET and POST cases WordPress is setting the `name` query var to the value passed in the form, this is what's causing the 404.

Comment: sure, i will test and get back to here.

Comment: Yes, you are absolute correct. Reserved query variables can not be used either in GET or POST variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rename your form fields so they don't clash with WordPress query vars, specifically `name`.

Reserved `$_GET` and `$_POST` terms in WordPress:

```
attachment
attachment_id
author
author_name
calendar
cat
category
category__and
category__in
category__not_in
category_name
comments_per_page
comments_popup
customize_messenger_channel
customized
cpage
day
debug
error
exact
feed
hour
link_category
m
minute
monthnum
more
name
nav_menu
nonce
nopaging
offset
order
orderby
p
page
page_id
paged
pagename
pb
perm
post
post__in
post__not_in
post_format
post_mime_type
post_status
post_tag
post_type
posts
posts_per_archive_page
posts_per_page
preview
robots
s
search
second
sentence
showposts
static
subpost
subpost_id
tag
tag__and
tag__in
tag__not_in
tag_id
tag_slug__and
tag_slug__in
taxonomy
tb
term
theme
type
w
withcomments
withoutcomments
year
```

Source: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms